# PhoneGap: get back to index.html

Tags: iphone, url, cordova, back

I want to use an external service in my PhoneGap app for iPhone.
The service take a success url to redirect user to the original page when the process has been completed.
What url should I pass to the service to get back to my PhoneGap app?
I have tried with file://www/index.html, but I get permission error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use absolute urls reliably in PhoneGap html pages. On android you have

```
file:///android_asset/www/index.html
```

but on iOS your url is something like

```
file:////var/mobile/Applications/[uuid]/[app name].app/www/index.html
```

You don't know that url in advance, so to get an absolute link to index.html you will need to get that url from document.location and either set it as the base url or save it for use in links.

Comment: I tried this in the simulator, but the file is not accessible from the app once it gets back. I actually can't test on the device: do you think it would be different?